# Routing requests to cgi with nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, web-hosting, fastcgi

I'm having trouble translating an application controller routing setup from Apache to nginx *without using `if`* , which is strongly discouraged.

What I want: serve requests for static files as-is if they exist, execute .php scripts if they exist, and route everything else to `/index.php$uri` (and execute that). More illustrative:

```
$ ls
index.php test.php image.png

GET /                  -> fcgi index.php/
GET /image.png         -> serve static
GET /test.php          -> fcgi test.php
GET /api/v1            -> fcgi index.php/api/v1
GET /api.php           -> fcgi index.php/api.php
```

In Apache, that would just be something simple like this, with mod_php figuring out if the resulting REQUEST_FILENAME is a script or not:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.+$ index.php [L]
```

In nginx, I cannot figure out how to get this to work. My current best try is this, which does not work as it tries to fcgi any request that looks like a script, including those that don't exist (see last example above). I'm on Debian with their default snippets etc.:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
}

location ~ [^/].php(/|$) {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

Using `if (-e $request_filename)` instead of `try_files` this should be possible, but as the manual so strongly discourages using `if`, I'd rather avoid it.

I would have expected this to be fairly common for software moving from Apache, but all the examples I found either redirect *all* requests to the application controller with no stand-alone scripts, or redirect none at all and only handle stand-alone scripts.